# Issue creating dynamic Menu when only 1 result - using DBATools

Tags: powershell, dbatools

I'm banging my head on this issue and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong, or why I get the results.

I'm using DBATools to gather SQL instances on a remote server (excluding SSRS if there).

Portion of the script is:

```
            Get-DBATools
            
            $SQLInstInfo = Find-DbaInstance -computername $Computer | Where { ($_.BrowseReply -NE $Null) }
            
            $menu = @{ }
            for ($i = 1; $i -le $SQLInstInfo.BrowseReply.SQLInstance.count; $i++)
            {
                Write-Color "`n $i. ", "$($SQLInstInfo.BrowseReply.SQLInstance[$i - 1]) " -Color White, Green
            
                $menu.Add($i, ($SQLInstInfo.BrowseReply.SQLInstance[$i - 1]))
            }
            
            [int]$ans = $(Write-Color "`nType the ", "Number ", "of the ", "SQL Instance ","desired: " -Color White, Green, White, Yellow, White -NoNewline; Read-Host)
            $Instance = $menu.Item($ans)
```

Previously I was just pulling the Instance info from registry, but that wasn't providing proper instance info if it was a SQL Failover Cluster, so I've swapped to using DBATools.

Anyway, if there are multiple instances, it works perfectly.

[image: multi instances]

But if there's only one instance, I get just the first letter of the instance name.

[image: single instance]

I'm just not seeing what I've done wrong.  I've tried several things, but nothing is panning out.  I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I know if I take out the [$i - 1], then for a single instance it would work, but when there are multiple instances, it would stick them all together.  I guess I could do a If/Then setup to check amount of instances first, and then do it with/without [$i - 1], but that just seems illogical.

Any insight or advice is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerShell likes to "flatten" pipeline output, so when `Find-DbaInstance` only returns 1 instance, the resulting variable value is no longer an array.

Use the array sub-expression operator `@(...)` to ensure the value assigned to `$SQLInstInfo` is an array regardless of how many instances `Find-DbaInstance ... |Where-Object ...` returns:

```
$SQLInstInfo = @(Find-DbaInstance -computername $Computer | Where { $null -ne $_.BrowseReply })
```

Additionally you want to change the loop to iterate over `$SQLInstInfo` rather than [the enumerated expression `$SqlInstInfo.BrowseReply.SQLInstance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.4#accessing-members-of-a-list-collection-object) - which will also get flattened when only a single value is resolved:

```
for ($i = 1; $i -le $SQLInstInfo.Count; $i++) {
    $instanceName = $SQLInstInfo[$i - 1].BrowseReply.SQLInstance
    Write-Color "`n ${i}. ", "${instanceName} " -Color White, Green

    $menu.Add("$i", $instanceName)
}
```

Comment: That was a good idea, but it still gives me the exact same result

Comment: @ComputerRecon I just noticed why it won't solve it alone, I've updated the answer :)

Comment: It's half working, but definitely got me on the right track now.  Well, it's working, but also generating an extra error about cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.  I should be able to get it figured out and will update as soon as I do.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh, I had commented out the orig @menu() which is where my null error was coming from.  I can definitely work with this.  I think I will need a few more tweaks, but it is generating the menu properly now.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Not sure if you'll see this, but using your method makes the menu perfectly, but the last section of the orig code is turning up $null.  I can't seem to get around it, even trying different variations of expanding property and whatnot.  It's odd.                                                                               ```[int]$ans = $(Write-Color "`nType the ", "Number ", "of the ", "SQL Instance ","desired: " -Color White, Green, White, Yellow, White -NoNewline; Read-Host)
            $Instance = $menu.Item($ans)```

Comment: @ComputerRecon Feel free to [ask another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), remember to include the exact error message :)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles across this...after using the provided answer (which worked great for what I was doing) I was having issues using the original `$Instance = $menu.Item($ans)`

I finally figured out a way to get it to work properly on all sql instances, so I could use the $Instance variable in many other places.

Final working code for this section of my script:

```
            $SQLInstInfo = @(Find-DbaInstance -computername $Computer | Where { $null -ne $_.BrowseReply })
            $menu = @{ }
            
            for ($i = 1; $i -le $SQLInstInfo.Count; $i++)
            {
                $instanceName = $SQLInstInfo[$i - 1].BrowseReply.SQLInstance
                Write-Color "`n ${i}. ", "${instanceName} " -Color White, Green
                $menu.Add("$i", $instanceName)
            }
            
            [int]$ans = $(Write-Color "`nType the ", "Number ", "of the ", "SQL Instance ","desired: " -Color White, Green, White, Yellow, White -NoNewline; Read-Host)
        
            $Instance = $SQLInstInfo[$ans - 1].BrowseReply.SQLInstance
```